# How much can a mule carry?

Tags: savage-worlds

Are mules subject to the same encumbrance rules as PCs, leading them to only be able to carry 40lbs of gear? Or is there a more realistic number someplace I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The encumbrance rules are intended for PCs, although [a rule of thumb recommended by the Savage Worlds Core Rules Brand Manager is to double the carrying capacity for each point of Size](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=252561#252561).  Thus a mule with Strength d8 and Size +2 would be able to carry 160lb without penalty, or 640lb with a -3 penalty.

However, from the [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule) [sources](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7154501_much-can-pack-mule-carry_.html) provided by @Phil, it seems a mule can normally carry around 20–30% of its body weight, so if you're aiming for a more realistic figure you could try a rule like "four-legged creatures double their carrying capacity".

Comment: I found a mention of that rule of thumb of Clint's but didn't manage to google up the original post. Nice find!